# How LSTM predicts without input data

Tags: lstm

I have a following question about predicting with LSTM model with keras in R. At the beginning I wasn't sure how the forecasting part works and I made the predictions of 1 time ahead using as the new data a simple vector of length of test period that goes from 1....length(test period). So basically I was not feeding any new data in the prediction phase and still the predictions were good. How is that even possible that the test period has been predicted well if I was not giving any new data from the test in the prediction phase?

Thank you in advance